# iOS: Renamed my app but sharing my app still uses old name

Tags: ios

Here is my situation: I recently renamed my app to YYY by changing the Display Name. Everything is working as expected except when I open the 3d menu on my app icon (by pressing hard with 3d touch) it says "Share XXX" where XXX is my old app name.

Does anyone know how to make it so that the 3d touch menu will show "Share YYY" instead of "Share XXX"?

Comment: Try reinstalling the app.

Comment: Just tried it, also tried uninstalling + restarting device. Both methods did not work

Comment: Have you ever tried installing it in some other simulator instance ?

Comment: Fresh simulator has same problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed my own problem. The issue is that I have added a custom UIApplicationShortcutItem in my plist file and all I needed to do was change the key UIApplicationShortcutItemTitle from "Share XXX" to "Share YYY"

Answer (score 0):

I do not think the name is duplicated anywhere. Maybe the old name has been cached by the operating system. Try restarting the device.